# Trying to reverse letter order in words with 5 or more letters in a string. This code does not crash but does not output anything either

Tags: python

```py
def spin(s):

    for word in s:
        if len(word) >= 5:
            w = ' '.join(w[::-1] for w in s.split())
            return w
            print(w)

s = "Twist and shout"

spin(s)
```

desired output: "tsiwT and tuohs"

Comment: You do a `return` before a `print`, so `print` is never reached.

Answer (score 2):

```
def spin(s):
    return ' '.join(word[::-1] if len(word) >= 5 else word for word in s.split())

print(spin("Twist and shout"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def reverse(x):
    x_list = list(s.split(" "))
    final_list = []
    for word in x_list:
        if len(word)>=5:
            word = word[::-1]
            final_list.append(word)
        else:
            final_list.append(word)
    final_word = " ".join(final_list)
    return final_word
```

Comment: This code is technically correct, but `return print(something)` is not a good idea.

Comment: you return the final_word and print it later...have changed it

Answer (score 0):

placeholders instead of split operation. just to show use of placeholders

```
string = "Twist and shout";
count = 0;
temp = 0;
array = [];
for element in range(0, len(string)): 
    count = count + 1; 
    if string[element] is " ":
        array.append(string[temp:count-1]);
        if len(array[-1]) > 4:
            array[-1] = (array[-1][::-1]) 
        temp = count;
array.append(string[temp:count]);
if len(array[-1]) > 4:
    array[-1] = (array[-1][::-1])
```